# Using Apache as proxy server + Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy, errordocument

I am trying to show custom page when tomcat is down, in order to do that i am usign apache server. I am trying to redirect all request to tomcat (localhost:8080), except request which start with '/error', how can I do that? I have tried something like this in httpd.conf file:

```
ErrorDocument 503 /error/503.html

<IfModule proxy_http_module>

ProxyPass /error http://localhost/ retry=0
ProxyPassReverse /error http://localhost/

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

</IfModule>
```

But didn't success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you even look at the httpd documentation for ProxyPass before asking your question?

You want

```
ProxyPass /error !
```

to exclude paths starting with `/error`